# Enable Anonymous Access to Subfolder Containing Handlers

Tags: iis, anonymous-authentication, access, ashx

I have a folder in an application that I would like available to the public. For example:

```
/_layouts/Handlers/Public/MyHandler.ashx
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268063/sharepoint-2010-ashx-handler-anonymous-access) that says I should enable anonymous access from IIS to that specific folder (which is why I created a public folder).

> 2.In IIS manager, turn on Anonymous Authentication to the layouts subfolder that contains your ashx file....

However I can't find any documentation on how to enable this via IIS. Can someone explain how to do this, or even better provide another option for anonymous access to a handler.

Answer (score 0):

Open IIS Manager, open the server in the left navigation, click Sites, click on the arrow next to your web application, locate _layouts and select it.

In the main window you see Authentication, double click it, select Anonymous Authentication and select Enable in the right hand side Actions

Comment: This says its already enabled however when I go to it, it prompts for a login, any idea what may be causing this?